# Update stops calling functions on specific situation. Read In detail please

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Update stops calling "*MoveTowardTaget();*" whenever my hole gets into any corner of the screen (*top-left*, *top-right*, *bottom-left* or *bottom-right*).

I'm generating random positions of hole and when the hole get to that point it fires and then another new random position is generated and hole starts moving toward that point.

Whenever it get to the corner of screen (top-left or top-right and bottom-left or bottom-right) it's stop calling MoveTowardTaget() function. just want to know the reason and suggestion to avoid this. This happens randomly not every time.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e3wdlJvNAFN1gpYzP7-Mf-fTJgFfGBLk/view?usp=sharing

screen shots from problem

```
  public class Hole : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        MoveTowardTaget();
        CheckInterval();
        print("Target Position Distance "+Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition));      

    }

    IEnumerator Fire()
    {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireDelay);
            //Firing Object
            }

        GenerateNewPosition();
    }

    void GenerateNewPosition()
    {
        Vector2 ScreenSize = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, this.transform.position.z));
        Xlimit = ScreenSize.x;
        Ylimit = ScreenSize.y;
        targetposition.x = Mathf.Clamp(Random.Range(-Xlimit, Xlimit), -(Xlimit * 0.8f), Xlimit * 0.8f);
        targetposition.y = Mathf.Clamp(Random.Range(-Ylimit, Ylimit), -(Ylimit * 0.7f), Ylimit * 0.5f);
        targetposition.z = this.transform.position.z;
        Debug.Log("NewPosition "+ targetposition);
    }

    void MoveTowardTaget()
    {

        //print("calling");
        if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition) > 0.1f)
        {
            //print("condition aaaa " + Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition));
            firedOnce = true;
            this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetposition, holemovingdpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
        else if (firedOnce)
        {
            //print("condition bbb " + Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition));

            StartCoroutine(Fire());
            firedOnce = false;
        }
    }
    void CheckInterval()
    {
        TotalTimeForPlay += Time.deltaTime;

        if (TotalTimeForPlay == firstInterval && !firstImplemented)
        {
            fireDelay = fireDelay * 0.3f;
            holemovingdpeed = holemovingdpeed + (holemovingdpeed * 0.2f);
            firstImplemented = true;
            TotalTimeForPlay = 0f;
        }
        if (TotalTimeForPlay >= SecondInerval && !seondImplemented)
        {
            fireDelay = fireDelay * 0.3f;
            holemovingdpeed = holemovingdpeed + (holemovingdpeed * 0.4f);

            seondImplemented = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think MoveTowardTarget is called every frame. But what will be in MoveTowardTaget() if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition) < 0.1f) and firedOnce is false?

Comment: Nothing. Okay thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that `MoveTowardTaget()` isn't being called, it's that nothing is happening inside of it.

You aren't properly accounting for the situation where the new goal is very near or equal to the old goal.  You should have the flag reset when a new goal is set instead of when movement (which may not happen) occurs:

```
void GenerateNewPosition() 
{ 
    Vector2 ScreenSize = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, this.transform.position.z)); 
    Xlimit = ScreenSize.x; 
    Ylimit = ScreenSize.y;
    targetposition.x = Mathf.Clamp(Random.Range(-Xlimit, Xlimit), -(Xlimit * 0.8f), Xlimit * 0.8f); 
    targetposition.y = Mathf.Clamp(Random.Range(-Ylimit, Ylimit), -(Ylimit * 0.7f), Ylimit * 0.5f); 
    targetposition.z = this.transform.position.z; 
    Debug.Log("NewPosition "+ targetposition); 

    firedOnce = true; 
} 

void MoveTowardTaget() 
{ 
    //print("calling"); 
    if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition) > 0.1f) 
    { 
        //print("condition aaaa " + Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition)); 
        this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetposition, holemovingdpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    } 
    else if (firedOnce) 
    { 
        //print("condition bbb " + Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, targetposition)); 
        StartCoroutine(Fire()); 
        firedOnce = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention any example ?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzaal I'm not sure what you mean. Did you try the code in the answer?